# Using the *compact* property of subsets in $R$ to prove Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

I have been asked to prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem with respect to a *bounded* sequence of real numbers by using the fact that *closed* and *bounded* subsets of $R$ are *compact*.

There is a hint along with the question stating that there are two cases: one where the same value appears infinitely many times in the sequence, and another where each value appears a finite number of times.

I have been attempting this question for a while, but I have been having trouble relating the *compact* property to the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1 : Every sequence $a_n$ contains a monotone subsequence.

The proof is hidden below, you can attempt this yourself or look at the proof (by hovering the mouse over it) if you like:

> Let us call $n \in \mathbb{N}$ special if $a_n > a_m$ for all $m> n$. Then, two possibilities arise. One is that there are infinitely many special points, in which case there is a decreasing subsequence. On the other hand, if there are finitely many special points, then take $n_1$ larger than all the special points. Since $n_1$ is not special, there is $n_2 > n_1$ such that $a_{n_2} \geq a_{n_1}$. Now $n_2$ is not special etc. so we can form an increasing subsequence.

Hint 2:A bounded monotone sequence converges. This proof I leave to you.

Hence, every bounded sequence has a monotone subsequence, which is also bounded hence converges. You don't at all need compactness in this proof.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just before you posted this, I realized that the solution is actually written in my textbook! The question is just asked differently. :P

Comment: That  is ok.  Two different solutions to the same problem can offer more insight by the tools that are used in the solution.

Comment: Just noticed that this particular proof doesn't use the compact property, which is what I am required to include in my answer..

Comment: That's a very important point. Indeed compactness was used nowhere.